# Are the smart quotes used in question titles seen using all the browsers?

Tags: support, questions

In english.SE, the quotation mark (*"*) used in the title is replaced by a smart quote. Are they visible in all the browsers, in any platform?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: They work in IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari on Windows XP and Windows 7.

Comment: They work in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari on Mac OS X too.

Comment: Works in Firefox, Chrome, and Midori on Linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: This question's title should probably have "smart quotes" in quotes, to make it easier to check whether or not they work in a given browser. Also, the resulting screenshots would create reference cycles, which are always fun ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are output in the HTML code as `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;`, so they should be supported on all reasonable browsers on all reasonable platforms.

Comment: I was wondering if somebody would see the title of the second question rendered differently because a comment to that question.

Comment: Lynx, being run in an xterm window on my Ubuntu Linux system, with various configurations that may be non-standard, shows them all as " (ASCII character code decimal 34). I'm not sure if this counts as a "reasonable" setup, though...

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: that sounds like "supported" to me.